# REST API - how to handle POST updates with an entity's child collection

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, entity-framework, rest

I'm building a REST API using ASP.NET Web API and Entity Framework 6 with MySQL.

Via a front-end [Angular.js] web app, users can `POST` an entity to the API to update it but I'm unsure how I should be handling any updates that might have been made to the entity's child collection.

At the moment I'm doing something like this:

```
    public async Task Post([FromBody]List<ConfiguredAPIDTO> configuredAPIs)
    {
        using (PAMDatabase db = new PAMDatabase(WebApiConfig.PAMConnectionString))
        {
            // Loop through each Configured API DTO object that was supplied
            foreach (ConfiguredAPIDTO Capi in configuredAPIs)
            {
                // Locate the corresponding entity in the database
                var dbcapi = db.context.configuredAPIs.FirstOrDefault(c => c.configuredAPIID == Capi.configuredAPIID);

                // Use AutoMapper to update existing entity object
                Mapper.Map<ConfiguredAPI, configuredAPI>(Capi, dbcapi);
            }

            // Save updated entities to DB
            await db.context.SaveChangesAsync(); // throws an InvalidOperationException
        }
    }
```

The thing is, each `ConfiguredAPIDTO` object actually has a child collection of `ConfiguredAPIExternalURLDTO` objects, as so:

```
public class ConfiguredAPIDTO
{
    public int configuredAPIID { get; set; }
    public string internalBaseURL { get; set; }
    public int orgID { get; set; }
    public bool preventDefaultEndpointAssignment { get; set;}

    public Api api { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ConfiguredAPIExternalURLDTO> configuredAPIExternalURLs { get; set; }

}

public class ConfiguredAPIExternalURL
{
    public string configuredAPIExternalBaseURL { get; set; }
    public int configuredAPIID { get; set; }
}
```

At the moment, I can confirm that AutoMapper is correctly updating the `configuredAPI` with the new Properties, and is also correctly updating the `configuredAPI.configuredAPIExternalURLs` child collection - but when I call `SaveChangesAsync()` I get an InvalidOperationException.

First stab at this and I'm unsure how much manual inspection I should be doing to help Entity Framework out here. Will it automatically remove any orphaned objects when I update the entity like this?  Or should I be manually comparing old and new child collections to see what has changed and doing my own deletion / insertion accordingly?  Also, does EF require that my foreign keys are correct, or is merely inserting an object into a collection enough for it to understand what's going on.   Perhaps my whole pattern is wrong here and I should be handling each entity separately.